# Error with beans in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm getting an error for the last instance of  in the file. Why is this? I am just trying to create some beans which hold a string which I can reference later.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:/simple-job-launcher-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/hibernate-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/autowire-context.xml" />

<bean id="str" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
 <constructor-arg value="string_1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="str2" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
  <constructor-arg value="string_1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Are you getting _an_ error or a **very specific error with a very specific stack trace**?

Comment: Also, what does spring-batch have to do with this?

Comment: an error. Simply a red "X" in Eclipse. The error is not defined from what I can see.

Comment: Hover over it. Alternatively, open the "Markers" view and look for it there.

Comment: Hmm nothing is displayed when hovering over it, and I can't seem to find it in the markers view. Does the code look like it should be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, the markup looks fine. Those two bean definitions at the end are syntactically correct. Try to initialize the `ApplicationContext`, see what error it produces at runtime.

Comment: Found the problem. Needed to put </beans> at the end. I'm so dumb.

Comment: I just assumed you left that out.